# How to install python 2.7 on RHEL6 32 bit machine?

Tags: python-2.7, repository, rpm, rhel, rhel6

I am stuck with installing python2.7 on my redhat6 , which has default python 2.6 installed. Also searched a lot for repository of '**python-deltarpm**' and '**deltarpm**' which is required for installing '**createrepo**', but didn't get. 
I added repo from dvd and from [https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/)  and **yum repolist** gives **repolist: 11,960**.
I want to install **pip** & **virtualenv** using python2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...I installed python2.7 as follows

```
cd /usr/src 
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tgz
tar xzf Python-2.7.13.tgz
cd Python-2.7.13
./configure
make altinstall
```

Answer (score 2):

[Python 2.7 is available as a software collection.](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python27/)  However, if I interpret the channel data correctly, it has only been released for x86-64, and there aren't even any i686 multlib RPMs.  I don't know why Red Hat is not shipping such RPMs; I suggest to contact customer support and see if they can provide builds.

Comment: Indeed, RHSCL is only built for 64-bit, see the [Release Notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/2.4_Release_Notes/chap-RHSCL.html#sect-RHSCL-Compatibility).

Comment: @Florian Weimer.no rpms...thats a sad news.